# Is sum of vector subspaces analogous to union of subsets?

Tags: linear-algebra, intuition, direct-sum

I was solving a question that said:
Prove or give a counterexample:
If $U_1, U_2, W$ are subspaces of $V$
such that
$V = U_1\oplus W$ and $V=U_2\oplus W$,
then $U_1=U_2$.
We can choose $V=\mathbb{R}^2,U_1=\operatorname{span}\{(1,0)\},U_2=\operatorname{span}\{(0,1)\},W=\operatorname{span}\{(1,1)\}$ as counterexample. But most of the time, the sum of subspaces looks analogous to the union of subsets, and it satisfies many analogous properties as well. For example, the formula for the dimension of the sum of subspaces is similar to the formula for the cardinality of the union of subsets. Also, a note from Sheldon Axler's text says:

> Sums of subspaces in the theory of vector spaces are analogous to unions of subsets in set theory. Given two subspaces of a vector space, the smallest subspace containing them is their sum. Analogously, given two subsets of a set, the smallest subset containing them is their union.

In this case, we take the analogy as follows:
If $U_1,U_2,W$ are subsets of $V$ such that $V = U_1\cup W$ and $V = U_2 \cup W$ with $U_1 \cap W=\emptyset$ and $U_2 \cap W = \emptyset$, then $U_1=U_2$.
This turns out to be true.

Can anyone give an intuitional explanation for this observation?

Comment: The union of two subspaces has no reason to be a subspace. So we (almost) *never* write the union of two subspaces. The "good" notion here is the sum.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Maybe you didn't get my question. I'm not asking for the union of subspaces. That is why in the analogy, I've replaced the word 'subspaces' with 'subsets'.

Comment: Subspaces are subsets... The sum of two subspaces *is not* the same thing as the union of the subspaces (viewed as subsets if you want). This is not the same thing, since the first one is always a subspace, whereas the second one is almost never a subspace. This is not the same thing, so I don't see why it should have the same properties.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I've made an edit to be more precise in asking what I meant.

Comment: As someone who has almost finished Axler's LADR, I can say that yes, sum of vector subspaces is similar to union of subsets, but not 100% the same. Unfortunately, I don't have a full list of differences or anything like that.

Comment: What the asker seems to be getting at is $U+V = \mathrm{Span}(U\cup V)$, which is true.

Comment: @CrabMan This comment is mostly what I was trying to explore. Anyway, thanks for the response.

Comment: Maybe this'll help you to get some intuition. Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$. Take the whole horizontal x-axis as the subspace $W$. Suppose you want to add something to $W$ to get the whole vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$. To do that, you can add the vertical y-axis as the subspace $U_1$. But alternatively, you can add the diagonal line $U_2 = \{(t, t) \mid t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ that goes through 0. Or alternatively, you can add any line other than the x-axis that goes through zero, and you'll still get the whole vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$.